# HTTP запрос через TCPClient

Tags: c#

Хочу получить веб-страничку используя не HttpWebRequest, а чистый TCP
В качестве подопытного взял вот этот сайт: on-line-teaching.com/index.html

```
        byte[] message = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("GET /index.html HTTP/1.1");
        string mess = "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1";
        TcpClient TClient = new TcpClient("on-line-teaching.com", 80);        
        NetworkStream stream = TClient.GetStream();
        BinaryReader R = new BinaryReader(stream); //поток для принятия данных
        BinaryWriter W = new BinaryWriter(stream); //поток для отправки данных
        W.Write(mess);
        byte[] buf = new byte[TClient.ReceiveBufferSize];    
        W.Write(mess);                                       // вариант 1
        // W.Write(message);                                 // вариант 2

        R.Read(buf, 0, TClient.ReceiveBufferSize); 
        TClient.Close();
        foreach (byte b in buf)
            Console.Write(b);
        Console.WriteLine(buf.Length);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Вариант 1: когда я в BinaryWriter отправляю string, связь устанавливается и пакет вродибы как проходит. Но в ответ я ничего не получаю. Так же перед запросом появляется странная точка (на рисунке видно) - не знаю что это.

[image: Вариант 1]

Вариант 2: если же я пишу byte[], то связь обрывается

[image: Вариант 2]

Собственно, в связи с этим у меня 2 вопроса:
1) в чём разница, пишу ли я в BinaryWriter string или byte[]
2) почему не приходит ответ в обоих случаях.
Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
string message = "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\n\n";
byte[] buf;
int totalRead = 0;
using (TcpClient TClient = new TcpClient("on-line-teaching.com", 80))
{
    NetworkStream stream = TClient.GetStream();
    using (BinaryWriter W = new BinaryWriter(stream, Encoding.ASCII, leaveOpen: true))
    {
        W.Write(message);
    }

    buf = new byte[TClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
    using (BinaryReader R = new BinaryReader(stream, Encoding.ASCII, leaveOpen: true))
    {
        int readThisTime;
        do
        {
            readThisTime = R.Read(buf, totalRead, buf.Length - totalRead);
            totalRead += readThisTime;
        } while (readThisTime > 0);
    }
}
foreach (byte b in buf.Take(totalRead))
    Console.Write($"{b:X2} ");
Console.WriteLine($"\nTotal bytes read: {totalRead}");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Пояснение:

1. В конце GET-запроса должно быть `\n\n`. Без этого запрос считается неоконченным, так что сервер терпеливо ждёт.
2. По сети в любом случае передаются байты. Когда вы передаёте строку, она декодируется в байты. Если вы укажете в конструкторе `BinaryWriter` кодировку, байты будут браться исходя из вашей кодировки.
3. `R.Read` возвращает не весь ответ сервера (он не знает, сколько читать, да и буфер может быть слишком мал или слишком велик), а кусок длиной в `readThisTime`. Вы должны, по идее, читать до тех пор, пока `readThisTime` не станет нулём (что означает, данных больше нет).
4. Обратите внимание, что буфер может исчерпаться, если ответ длинный. В этом случае вы должны создавать новые буфера, чтобы прочитать весь ответ сервера.
5. Имеет смысл закрывать открытые ресурсы автоматически, при помощи `using`, а не вручную.