# Получить web страницу через TcpClient

Tags: c#, http, tcpclient

Пытаюсь получить содержимое страницы через TcpClient (c#).
Взял за основу ответ [HTTP запрос через TCPClient](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/519091/http-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-tcpclient)
По какой то причине получаю ответ длинной 0.
Уже пробовал брать заголовки из Chrome, результат тот же.

Прошу подсказать каким образом лучше всего (и быстрее по скорости работы) получать web страницу на c# (я знаю о существовании webclient и HttpWebRequest).

Причем как то странно, какие-то страницы удается получить с любыми заголовками, а на требуемой уже перепробовал все что только можно (нужно получить страницу https://api.livecoin.com/exchange/order_book)

Comment: Быстрее всего по скорости работы будет прямая работа с сетевыми устройствами. Вы точно этого хотите?

Comment: Если вы получаете содержимое веб страницы с внешнего адреса, то там как минимум 99.9% времени будет занимать передача данных по сети, а остальное - выполнение кода HttpWebRequest. Нет смысла пытаться сделать быстрее.

Answer (score 0):

Если не принципиально описанным вами способом то можно сделать так:

используя

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;

public string GetAllSourceCode(string url)
    {
        using (HttpClient _client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (HttpResponseMessage _response = client.GetAsync(url).Result)
            {
                using (HttpContent _content = _response.Content)
                {
                    _source = _content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    return _source;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

скармливать метод адресом(url), и получать все содержимое страницы...

Comment: А как бы есть метод `GetStringAsync`, и `GetStreamAsync`, и можно обойтись без всех этих наворотов. И еще, не просто результат извлекать, а запросить `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`.

Comment: Согласен на все 100%
предложенный мною метод самый примитивный...